# Placeholder skeleton in flutter

Tags: flutter, placeholder

I'm using `flutter` for my mobile apps. I'm looking Placeholder skeleton to show that something is loading. Here is an example how Material UI is showing [Skeleton React Component](https://material-ui.com/components/skeleton/#variants) I'm looking something similar to this in flutter is there any library, widget or something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called a `Shimmer`, you can use the package below to achieve that in `Flutter`:

[shimmer](https://pub.dev/packages/shimmer)